RStudio Project Template not working in non-main branch
I followed the guidelines in https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html and wrote code in a non-main branch inside this R package: https://github.com/jhudsl/ottrpal/tree/127-rstudio-project-template. The dcf file is here and the the template function is here.
However, this template doesn't show up in the RStudio IDE's Project Wizard, and I'm thinking the reason might be that this code is on a non-main branch.
So, my question: Does the dcf file and template R function need to be placed in the main branch for this to show up in the Project Wizard?
Thank you.

This doesn't really have anything to do with git branches outside of the need to have that particular version of your package installed in your R library.
You can install from that branch like so (or you could install locally provided you have that branch checked out):
devtools::install_github("jhudsl/ottrpal@127-rstudio-project-template")

After installing your package, I have come to the conclusion there is something wrong with your logo file. Perhaps it is too large? For example, the {thesisdown} logo is 124 KB whereas your image is 1.31 MB.
After removing the reference to the logo from your dcf file, the template started showing up in the new project wizard.
Similarly, after a fresh install and scaling your logo down to 25% (now 102 KB) with Gimp, the template started showing up in the new project wizard.

I am also finding trouble with the logo.png file, which I've verified is 17 KB.  Removed: it works.
